# how to know type file in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, types

I create one application that in self use any file with any format.

I want know this file to read that what is type?

please explain me more this issue.

Comment: extract last components after `.` you will know file type and extension.

Comment: can you tell me more please? (with code)

Comment: NSString *fileName; NSString *extenstion=[[fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] lastObject];

Comment: Also `-[NSString pathExtension]` and `-[NSString lastPathComponent]`

Comment: What do you mean by "know file type in Xcode"?

Comment: mean I can understand file type in objective c (iphone)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I so confused of your code

Comment: @AnoopVaidya please explain more

Comment: 1. Your problem is incomplete. 2.From where you are getting your file/fileName. 3.What type you looking for? 4.If you convert .avi to .txt filetype remains same, it wont show all the dialoges in txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code example

```
NSString *file = @"…"; // path to some file
CFStringRef fileExtension = (CFStringRef) [file pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) NSLog(@"It's an image");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)) NSLog(@"It's a movie");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText)) NSLog(@"It's text");

CFRelease(fileUTI);
```

Comment: my friend does it work for iphone??

Comment: Its objective c code .and if you are developing app for iphone.it will work.Its just sample code you have to implement it according to your requirement

Comment: my friend I get this error "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_UTTypeConformsTo", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o

Comment: Probably you don't have VideoOverviewControllerDelegate (i don't know, what it is) in linked frameworks. [How to add framework to project][1].


  [1]: http://www.thinketg.com/Company/Blogs/11-03-20/Xcode_4_Tips_Adding_frameworks_to_your_project.aspx#axzz1aZNmWDNZ

Answer (score 0):

You can get file name and extension of filepath programmatically .There are methods on `NSString` that do this. Look at `-[NSString pathExtension]` and `-[NSString lastPathComponent]`, both defined in `NSPathUtilities.h`.

You can also get the filename without extension by using `[NSString stringByDeletingPathExtension];`

Comment: in my xcode dont exist NSPathUtilities.h

Comment: which version of xcode you are using... ??

Comment: 4.5 but when I import NSPathUtilities.h xcode dont know its

Comment: if you implement -[NSString pathExtension] and -[NSString lastPathComponent] without importing  NSPathUtilities.h,it should work... does it work???? have you tried????

Comment: yes I do but not worked XD

Comment: Ok...lets try both of us,and soon i'll find a good solution for you.